# Where does the Total Commander store the settings to synchronize directories?

Tags: total-commander

I'm using Total Commander (v. 8.01) for simple backups of few directories (like [here](http://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Synchronize_directories)). My IT support recently migrated me to a new account and I lost the settings of folders I saved when I call 'Synchronize directories'. I still have access to folders from my old account (Windows Server 2008) so my question is - where does the TC store this information? Is it possible to rescue it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this settings are stored in:

```
C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\GHISLER\wincmd.ini
```

Copying this file from my old account sorted the issue.